# Using Cypress Over SmartGWT Framework

Tags: cypress, smartgwt

I'm trying to identify DOM elements using cypress 6.3.0 but sometimes I'm getting the following error over one element:

> "Timed out retrying after 4050ms: cy.click() failed because this
> element is detached from the DOM.
>
> src="https://localhost/..../removeRow.png"
> width="16" height="16" align="TEXTTOP" name="isc_30main" border="0"
> suppress="TRUE">
>
> Cypress requires elements be attached in the DOM to interact with
> them.
>
> The previous command that ran was:
>
> > cy.get()
>
> This DOM element likely became detached somewhere between the previous
> and current command.
>
> Common situations why this happens:
>
> - Your JS framework re-rendered asynchronously
> - Your app code reacted to an event firing and removed the element
>
> You typically need to re-query for the element or add 'guards' which
> delay Cypress from running new commands."

and sometimes I do not get any error. It seems like sometimes it founds the element and sometimes it doesn't.

I'm in the process of trying what they explain here: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/07/22/do-not-get-too-detached/ but while I do that I would like to know if anybody has already succeded in using Cypress for doing e2e tests over a Web application using SmartGWT framework. If so, can you tell me please if it's necessary doing any additional configuration or using a specific library that allows these element's identification?

¿Any comments?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the code you tried.